# How can I change bash script -code to Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, git-bash

Hi Guys how can i change bash script code to Python3 .I want to use a Python script.

```
Final=Sys_"$series".txt
F_final=Pri"$series".txt
awk '{print $4}' $Final |grep "Y*\."|sort |uniq > $F_final


awk 'FNR==NR { c[$1] = 0; next; } # file2.txt
     $4 in c { c[$4]++ } # file1.txt
     END { for (x in c) printf("%s: Total =%d\n", x, c[x]) }
' $F_final $Final | sort > Result_"$series".txt
```

Comment: Please post where you are stuck

Comment: @mzjn Thank you,actually i used a few day(Python) i am trying but i can not do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with "[How to port an awk script to Python](https://opensource.com/article/19/11/awk-to-python)"

And also consider using  [`alecthomas/pawk`](https://github.com/alecthomas/pawk)

> PAWK - A Python line processor (like AWK)
> PAWK aims to bring the full power of Python to AWK-like line-processing.

That way, you can translate those awk directives into similar python ones.